# How to remove the for loop in the following MATLAB code?

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, for-loop, time

I need to perform the following computation in an image processing project. It is the logarthmic of the summation of H3. I've written the following code but this loop has a very high computation time. Is there any way to eliminate the for loop?

```
    for k=1:i
        for l=1:j
            HA(i,j)=HA(i,j)+log2((H3(k,l)/probA).^q);
        end;
    end;
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
for i=1:256
for j=1:240

    probA = 0;
    probC = 0;

    subProbA = H3(1:i,1:j);
    probA = sum(subProbA(:));

    probC = 1-probA;    

    for k=1:i
        for l=1:j
            HA(i,j)=HA(i,j)+log2((H3(k,l)/probA).^q);
        end;
    end;

    HA(i,j)=HA(i,j)/(1-q);

    for k=i+1:256
        for l=j+1:240
            HC(i,j)=HC(i,j)+log2((H3(k,l)/probC).^q);
        end;
    end;

    HC(i,j)=HC(i,j)/(1-q);


    e1(i,j) = HA(i,j) + HC(i,j); 
    if e1(i) >= emax
        emax = e1(i);
        tt1 = i-1;
    end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Do you need to touch every pixel in the image?  If you do, you're going to need two loops anyway... one for the x axis, one for the y axis.

Comment: Yes, I need to visit all the pixels.

Comment: Are you visiting all of the pixels with i and j, or with k and l?

Comment: What are the sizes of `probA` and `q`? Aren't you using these two loops as nested into two more outer loops with `i` and `j` as iterators? It seems like it.

Comment: i and j are intensity values. k and l are used to visit all the pixels in H3. Actually it's the joint histogram of two images. probA and q are constant values.

Comment: You can't eliminate those loops.  Those loops are there to touch every pixel, and you just told us that is a requirement.

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the computation?
I'll post the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the two loops are nested inside some other outer loops that are iterated with `i` and `j` (though using `i` and `j` as iterators are not the best practices) and also assuming that `probA` and `q` are scalars, try this -

```
HA(i,j) = sum(sum(log2((H3(1:i,1:j)./probA).^q)))
```

Using the above code snippet, yon can replace your actual code posted in the EDIT section with this -

```
for i=1:256
    for j=1:240

        subProbA = H3(1:i,1:j);
        probA = sum(subProbA(:));
        probC = 1-probA;

        HA(i,j) = sum(sum(log2((subProbA./probA).^q)))./(1-q);        
        HC(i,j) = sum(sum(log2((subProbA./probC).^q)))./(1-q);

        e1(i,j) = HA(i,j) + HC(i,j);
        if e1(i) >= emax
            emax = e1(i);
            tt1 = i-1;
        end
    end
end
```

Note that in this code, `probA = 0;` and `probC = 0;` are removed as they are over-written anyway later in the original code.

Comment: as you do not know the size of `H3` , i think it should be `HA(i,j) = sum(sum(log2((H3(1:i,1:j)./probA).^q)))`.

Comment: @Nishant Thanks, that was a bug indeed! Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that q is scalar value, this code removes all the four `for` loops. Also in your given code you are calculating the maximum value of `e1` only along the first column. If that is so then you should put in out of the second loop

```
height = 256;
width = 240;
a = repmat((1:height)',1,width);
b = repmat(1:width,height,1);
probA = arrayfun(@(ii,jj)(sum(sum(H3(1:ii,1:jj)))),a,repmat(1:width,height,1));
probC = 1 - probA;
HA = arrayfun(@(ii,jj)(sum(sum(log2((H3(1:ii,1:jj)/probA(ii,jj)).^q)))/(1-q)),a,b);
HC = arrayfun(@(ii,jj)(sum(sum(log2((H3(ii+1:height,jj+1:width)/probC(ii,jj)).^q)))/(1-q)),a,b);
e1 = HA + HC;
[emax tt_temp] = max(e1(:,1));
tt1 = tt_temp - 1;
```